# simplesamlphp_auth installation fails on Centos 8-server

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

I am trying to install simplesamlphp_auth to Centos 8/Drupal 8 server according the instructions on:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/apigee-developer-portal-kickstart/integrate-simplesamlphp-
authentication

When I run the given command I get the following output:

```
composer require drupal/simplesamlphp_auth:3.x-dev drupal/simplesamlphp_custom_attributes --prefer-dist
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Using version ^1.0 for drupal/simplesamlphp_custom_attributes
./composer.json has been updated
> DrupalProject\composer\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - don't install drupal/simplesamlphp_auth 3.x-dev|install drupal/simplesamlphp_auth dev-3.x
    - Installation request for drupal/simplesamlphp_auth 3.x-dev -> satisfiable by drupal/simplesamlphp_auth[3.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: remove simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.17.7
    - Conclusion: don't install simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp v1.17.7
    - drupal/simplesamlphp_auth dev-3.x requires simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp ^1.18.2 -> satisfiable by simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp[v1.18.2, v1.18.3, v1.18.4].
    - Can only install one of: simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp[v1.18.2, v1.17.7].
    - Can only install one of: simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp[v1.18.3, v1.17.7].
    - Can only install one of: simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp[v1.18.4, v1.17.7].
    - Installation request for simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp (locked at v1.17.7) -> satisfiable by simplesamlphp/simplesamlphp[v1.17.7].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

So it seems, that for some reason the new enough simplesamlphp-package is not installable.

I have tried (in vain, though) to harvest the web about this problem, which should not be totally uncommon IMHO.

Any hints how to tackle the problem?

wbr

Hank

Comment: It’s the last line under problem 1 - a dependency of a module you’re installing or updating is locked to an incompatible version. Update that package first, require the right version of it along with your require command, or try the existing command with `—update-with-dependencies`. Last option is sometimes a bit nuclear so I’d try others first

Comment: Thank you, your answer led me to the old installation of the module which caused the problem.

Comment: Unless you are doing development work on the module, it's probably not the best idea to check out the `3.x-dev` branch. You'd be better off taking the last stable tag before that, or a specific commit on the `3.x-1.x` branch if you really want to work off the newest code. Pegging your project to shifing code (which you must assume -dev branches are) can result in your site suddenly being broken when you update. Dev branches don't have an obligation to be bug free.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trouble. The problem was caused because I had somewhere in the past installed those modules to this (test) site of my own and forgotten it totally. After removing the old simplesamlphp_auth things seemed to go OK.